# Не удается занести значение в базу

Tags: node.js, olap

Есть такой код:

```
let duckdb = require('duckdb');
let db = new duckdb.Database(':memory:'); // or a file name for a persistent DB
let con = db.connect();

con.run('CREATE TABLE a (i INTEGER)');
let stmt = con.prepare('INSERT INTO a VALUES (?)');

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  stmt.run(i);
}
stmt.finalize();

con.all('SELECT * FROM a', function(err, res) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  console.log(res)
});
```

После его запуска - в консоли можно увидеть следующее:

```
[
  { i: 0 }, { i: 1 },
  { i: 2 }, { i: 3 },
  { i: 4 }, { i: 5 },
  { i: 6 }, { i: 7 },
  { i: 8 }, { i: 9 }
]
```

Если обратиться к программе `DBeaver` и посмотреть наличие занесенных результатов в таблицу - то таковых обнаружить не удается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке взять значения из базы через програмный код следующим образом:

```
let duckdb = require('duckdb');
let db = new duckdb.Database(':memory:'); // or a file name for a persistent DB
let con = db.connect();

con.all('SELECT * FROM a', function(err, res) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  console.log(res)
});
```

Получаем результат:

```
undefined:0


[Error: Catalog Error: Table with name a does not exist!
Did you mean "pg_am"?
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM a
                      ^] {
  errno: -1,
  code: 'DUCKDB_NODEJS_ERROR'
}
```

Вопрос:
Что я упускаю из виду и как необходимо заносить и получать данные из базы в данной технологии?

Comment: Во второй строчке же видно, что она создается в памяти, т.е. доступна только текущему процессу без сохранения.

Comment: Допустим. Но каким образом занести данные в саму базу?
(не в память.)

Comment: Я с этой базой не работал, но судя по справочнику, как и многие другие - просто [создать реальный файл](https://duckdb.org/docs/connect) не используя специального имени `:memory:`. По идее он должен сохраниться в указанном пути - к нему и подключаться.

Comment: 'memory' тоже можно использовать - просто без двоеточия по крайям. Единственный момент, что запись может происходить даже в том случае если добавить расширение с .txt
И тогда возникает вопрос - как конкретно сохранять файл и с каким конкретно расширением.
(либо без расширения)
Пока что в доке не нашел этого.

Comment: `memory` без двоеточия, это и есть обычное имя файла, поэтому и работает. Расширения во всех подобных базах не имеет никакого значения. Если программа использует несколько файлов DB в выделенном каталоге, например `new duckdb.Database('data/users')` можно и не писать расширения. Расширения удобны для каталога с различными типами файлов, что'б визуально можно было их различать. Обычно так и называют `*.db`.